# CKEDITOR doesn't style my text that comes from the DB

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I'm inputting data into a rich textarea with CKEDITOR. That data is being sent to the database. But when I do a `SELECT` to get the text back to output it, the applied styles aren't applied to it.

Example:
In my CKEDITOR I input the text 'Well worked today' and I put the word worked in bold/strong. then it gets saved in my DB as

`<p>Well<strong>worked</strong>today</p>`

Then I do a `SELECT` to output that text to my screen.

But the the word isn't being bold
But when looking in debug console it is marked as

`<p>Well<strong>worked</strong>today</p>`

The same can be said if I'm trying to give it an other color.

How I output the text onto my screen: `echo $row->text;`

How I embed my CKEDITOR:

```
$text = array('name' => "text",'class' => "ckeditor");
echo form_textarea($text);
```

Why isn't it showing the applied styles?

Comment: When you print the text do you actually see the tags. I mean in the example above, do you see *<strong>worked</strong>* or it is only *worked* shown, but no style applied to it. Also will be nice if you give us a url to check.

Comment: Site isn't online yet, so can't show you an url. But it only shows **worked**, but in the devtools it shows <strong>worked</strong>

Answer (score 0):

If you removed some stylings form the toolbar and from the CK editor instance itself, the window will accept only styling tags allowed after "lightening" the editor.

For instance, if you make an instance of editor with only basic styles toolbar, heading styles would immediately be converted to standard text, i.e. p tags, but strong, italic and strikethrough would be rendered properly.

Comment: Do you mean when I downloaded it from the website? Because I indeed made a custom build for it. But After I downloaded it, I never changed anything to the files of CKEDITOR

Comment: In the call itself. You can add toolbargroup config to build custom toolbar and limit or extend available styling options.

If this is not the case, try figuring out does something strip your html tags during saving data do DB or fetching data from DB.

Often there is strip html tags option used by the developers when saving Post data to DB, it shouldnt be done with data from ck editor...

Comment: It seems that my reset.css is terminating the style of ckeditor itself. Is there a way around this?